# FOS user bundle Registration "Entity of type \Entity\User is missing an assigned ID for field 'id'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I've installed `FOS user bundle` to manage login & registration features, but when I try to register a new user I receive the following error:

```
    Entity of type ****\****\Entity\User is missing an assigned ID for field 'id'.
    The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be
    populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically
    generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.
```

This is my User.php class:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php
namespace  ***\***\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */

class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;
```

and this is my User.orm.yml:

```
****\****\Entity\User:
type:  entity
table: fos_user
fields:
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
```

I know that the problem appears when persisting the data of a new user, but I don't know how to make `Symfony` generate this `id` field.
Thanks!

Comment: Ok I've removed `generator` key, but if I remove also the `yml` settings files I will receive an error @bartek

Comment: Add 4 spaces before `strategy` key

Comment: `fields:
        id:
            id:
                type: integer
                strategy: AUTO`

Comment: No, `strategy` should be under `generator` key

Comment: `id` is a section on it's own (like `fields`, `oneToMany`, etc). Either drop the first `id` so that it is a regular field or move the whole `id` section so that it is at the same level and outside of `fields`.

Comment: Ok, I've just put it at the same level and outside of fields, but this doesn't solve my problem. I think I'm making confusion with Annotations and `YAML`, but when I try to delete `YAML` files I get the error `no mapping file found named *****` @Qoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your yml should looks like

```
type:  entity
table: fos_user
id:
     id:
         type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
fields:
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Your `yml` configuration is wrong, try with:

```
type:  entity
table: fos_user
fields:
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
```

Comment: Ok I've edited it, but I still receive the same error  @bartek

Comment: I've tried removing annotations, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem.
This is my User.php Class:

```
<?php

namespace *****\*****\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
```

And I've just deleted ALL `YAML` configurations files, it was a conflict problem between Annotations and `YAML` . Now registration and login work fine.